# previewing what a .NET HttpResponse object will post (obtaining cURL or similar serialised output)

Tags: c#

I am not getting the response I am wanting for the following code:

```
var multipart = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var empty = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n\r\n\r\n");
HttpContent content = new ByteArrayContent(empty);
content.Headers.Add("name", "jform[ical_url]");
multipart.Add(content);
...[cut for brevity]...
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseCookies = false })
   using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new System.Uri("http://icalendar.org") })
   {
       var response = await client.PostAsync("/validator", multipart);
```

I know exactly what I would like the POST request to look like (having used Firebug's 'copy cURL' menu item).

Is there a way to see what the client.PostAsync will send, or an extension to serialise the multipart variable above so that I can compare with the cURL string from a successful post?

Thank you.

Comment: Try [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or other http debuggers available.

Comment: I agree with Mehrzad and I recommend http://www.prefix.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding the delegating handler has provided some of the answer, as per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924996/logging-request-response-messages-when-using-httpclient#18925296).

I had not clearly explained that this was a class library. I tried Crowcoders advice, but I couldn't get it to work, and as the entire solution contains no WebAPI or MVC or similar projects, and I am trying to post to a validation site to check certain unit tests meet a spec. Briefly looking through the Stackify Prefix docs, I think the ability to handle this kind of scenario is in the pipeline, but not released as yet.

As I would love to know if any defaults are being added to the header (Accept, Language etc), I might look at Fiddler.