# Meaning of "The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response" in HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, http, .net-core

When awaiting an `HttpClient.PostAsync` response, I sometimes see an error stating *"The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response"*:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
```

That's a pretty cryptic error; I suppose I can conceive of what an "invalid" response might possibly be (i.e. a syntactically-invalid HTTP response, like one that jumps straight into headers without a status line), but what on earth is an "unrecognized" response to a HTTP request? The message seems like nonsense.

What circumstances can actually trigger this error, under the hood?

Comment: This can happen when the remote server returns really odd things like malformed headers. What are you posting to? Can you check the actual content to see if it's correct?

Comment: I could probably figure out a way to do that if I could reproduce the error at will, @DavidG - but currently it seems to happen to me randomly and rarely, which makes doing any careful inspection to see exactly what's going along the wire a bit tricky. Hence asking here - to try and figure out what the *possibilities* even are for what could trigger this.

Comment: Oh, transient and infrequent errors, the most fun of all the errors to debug! It's likely to be malformed headers I would guess, like `Header : Value` instead of `Header: Value`. Not much else I think we can help with here without seeing some actual returned data :/

Comment: You could [log all your responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924996/logging-request-response-messages-when-using-httpclient) until you get the error?

Comment: This _may_ provide some insight. [https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14897](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14897).

Comment: It happened to me when I used "Bearer" instead of "Basic" in Authorization header. I was expecting a HTTP 401 to happen in this case, but...

Answer (score 7):

You can reproduce this 100% of the time when calling an https only endpoint using an http schemed call. So for instance calling an API at:

```
https://www.mysecureapi.com
```

using

```
http://www.mysecureapi.com
```

Comment: This was exactly my error.  I had inadvertently switched to https, but had http in the config.

Comment: I am getting the same error. I changed `Https` to `Http` but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @user3502626 And? The question was not about how to fix the error - it asked how to reproduce it.

Comment: It is working for me... Thank you thank you so much

Answer (score -2):

Probable case would be you did a http request without authorization token or header. If you are trying to call a secured method or api, it needs a secured token to be shared or validated in order to get or post data.

Comment: That seems unlikely. APIs typically return a 401 or 403 response in this case, which is still a valid HTTP response.

Comment: @MarkAmery that is exactly what happened to me that caused this error.  Calling http instead of https, you DONT get a valid http response.

Comment: @paqogomez But this answer has nothing to do with HTTP vs HTTPS.

Comment: I think it does.  OP states that doing an http request without token (which would make it https if it was with token).  Trying to call a "secured" method is another indicator.  While yes, I can see some ambiguity there, I think they are talking about http vs https

Comment: @paqogomez The TLS protocol used to encrypt HTTPS connections doesn't involve anything commonly referred to as a "token" as far as I know. The normal meaning of "authorization token" is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_token - a token that identifies a login session or a user, usually sent in a cookie or a custom HTTP header. Unrelated to HTTPS.