# What causes "WinHttpException: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response" in HttpClient?

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core-2.0

**PROBLEM:**

I am trying to access data from a remote Bugzilla server using Bugzilla's REST API. Whenever I await a response from `HttpClient.GetAsync`, this [exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5An4.png) is thrown.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED:**

In an effort to understand the exception, I've investigated the following SO questions and GitHub issues:

- [Meaning of “The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response” in HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843714/meaning-of-the-server-returned-an-invalid-or-unrecognized-response-in-httpclie)
- [The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response" error when ...](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14897)
- [HttpClient fails with "The server returned an invalid or unrecognized ...](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20066)

**CORE CODE:**

The purpose of the code below is to get the Bugzilla version of the server at `_url_version`. For example, if I set `_url_version = "https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/rest/version"`, I get a valid [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0j4Q.png).

```
// Get version, dummy test to ensure REST API is working via http requests
public async Task<string> GetVersion()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(_url_version);
        string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json).version;
    }
}
```

**QUESTION:**

What is the meaning of this exception? What could be causing the communication break between my application and the remote Bugzilla server?

Comment: That URL returns a gzipped response, See: [Decompressing GZip Stream from HTTPClient Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990601/decompressing-gzip-stream-from-httpclient-response)

Comment: @AlexK I serialize the response into an object. For the example URL, the serialization works fine. The problem is actually getting the response from a different URL.

Comment: Sorry I missed the working bit.  Have you tried tracing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924996/logging-request-response-messages-when-using-httpclient

Comment: I'll give that a whirl and see what I can find. Thanks Alex.

Comment: @AlexK [Here](http://textuploader.com/dxyxp) is the relevant trace for the exception. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some digging, I was able to resolve this issue by *updating Bugzilla* to 5.0.4.

**ROOT CAUSE:**

By using [Curl](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html), I was able to manually examine the headers from the Http response ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK1VA.png)). The exception was being caused by noise in the response:

*Bugzilla.pm:sysread() is deprecated on :utf8 handles. This will be a fatal error in Perl 5.30 at C:/...*

For some reason, this issue with a perl module was being echoed on the server side.

**SOLUTION:**

According the [Bugzilla 5.0.4 release notes](https://www.bugzilla.org/releases/5.0.4/release-notes.html), the issue was resolved. I updated my Bugzilla installation and the REST API worked as intended.

Hopefully this is helpful to someone out there!