# Posts, Puts fail with 401, but not if Fiddler is running

Tags: c#, httpclient, fiddler

We have several machines in our department where when Post and Put calls are made they are failing with a 401.   When these same calls are made on a different machine they work fine.

When we remote into one of these workstations and run some httpclient tests we get the 401 unauthorized responses, but running this same code from another workstation works fine.

When we turn fiddler on and capture and decrypt the https the post and puts go through just fine on these "bad" stations.   We are at a loss as to the issue.  We have looked over Fiddler documentation and even the following:  https://www.telerik.com/blogs/help!-running-fiddler-fixes-my-app-, but nothing has solved the issue.

It feels like the workstation, but we need to isolate what it is on the workstation as we have three now with the issue.

Anyone have a similar issue and found a solution?

Cheers,

Jester

Comment: Does any proxy settings defined? When fiddler runs, it override the proxy settings that may be the reason the APIs work when fiddler is running.

Comment: User1672994 - proxy settings are off on the box, (windows 10).   Automatically detect settings was initially on but setup script and use proxy server were off.   Turned off automatically detect settings and issue persists.

Comment: You should set only the Trun on "Automatically detect settings" option. Uncheck the rest of the option.

Comment: Make sure the filters tab is disabled. And if Fiddler makes problems why not simply [log the messages on c# level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924996)?

Comment: User1672994 - all other options are unchecked.

Comment: Robert - Fiddler solves the problems.   Fiddler makes our Posts and Puts work when capturing traffic.