# Calling Api with header, username and password in C#

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am trying to get data from this api [codaBox](https://doc.codabox.com/)
I've tested it with [swagger](https://inspector.swagger.io/builder)
but when I am trying with [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) I am getting a error code 401. I am using the right header, username and password.

I tested it with [swagger](https://inspector.swagger.io/builder) with the same credentials and I've got data with it.

```
try
{
    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Username:password");
    Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
    Client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myurl");

    Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Software-Company", "myToken");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.GetAsync("");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    // Above three lines can be replaced with new helper method below
    // string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

    Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
}
catch (HttpRequestException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
    Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
}
```

I would like to get 200 status code.

Comment: Have you tried setting the user agent? This usually causes some issues if you don't do that

Comment: Also inspecting a succesful login attempt in your browser using tools like wireshark/fiddler may help you getting your automated code to work.

Comment: You should at least read the response body for certain status codes before calling `EnsureSuccessStatusCode`. Most OAuth providers provide an error message in the response body.

Comment: Did you compare your bearers already?

Comment: Did you try testing the API call in Postman? If you get it to work there, Postman can generate call for you.

Comment: i tried but no content no exception

Comment: If you hardcoded your password for testing or something, make sure it is escaped properly. Example: `asdf\t` -> `asdf\\t`

Answer (score -1):

You need to replace `"Username:password"` with the actual user and password separated by : `"{your actual username}:{your actual password}"`

Also Web is UTF8 (Ascii works sometimes as it's a subset) but not always:

```
var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Username:password");
```

Comment: of course i did it i just didn't want share my password and username all over the internet -)

Comment: @bobnkusi I see, then see my edit. Try changing to UTF8

Comment: The example you have, is the correct way to use Basic authentication. I think you need to double check that everything sent is correct. Try using Fillder or some other tool.

Comment: Or you can use a logging handler to see the exact request. See example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924996/logging-request-response-messages-when-using-httpclient