# How to capture HTTPS requests from an exe to ASP.NET Web API to examine the request details?

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, asp.net-web-api, https, network-traffic

I have a .Net Windows .exe created with visual studio that makes https requests to ASP.NET Web API services running on an IIS Server. How can I capture the https requests from the exe to examine the details?

Comment: By using Wireshark? https://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: Or create your own [handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924996/logging-request-response-messages-when-using-httpclient/18925296).