# Get the raw request that is sent with HttpClient and HttpRequestMessage

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

In my C# code running .NET 6 (Azure Function) I am sending an `HttpRequestMessage` using `HttpClient`. It doesn't work but it should work, so I want to get the **raw** request that I am sending, including the header, so I can compare with the documentation and see the differences.

In the past I have used Fiddler but it doesn't work for me now, probably because of some security settings on my laptop. So I am looking for a solution within the world of Visual Studio 2022 or .NET 6 where I can get the raw request out for troubleshooting purposes.

This question is not really about code, but here is my code anyway.

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://myendpoint.com/rest/something");

var apiToken = "AOU9FrasdgasdfagtHJNV";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + apiToken);

var message = new
{
    sender = "Hey",
    message = "Hello world",
    recipients = new[] { new { id = 12345678} }
};

request.Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(message), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript");
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

When `SendAsync` is invoked, I wish to know what exactly is sent, both header and content.

Comment: The request doesn't work, right? What is the exact response code you're getting? Have you tried using ILogger to log the response? 

Also, HttpResponseMessage has a property of type HttpRequestMessage that gives you  information about the request that led to that response. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.requestmessage?view=net-6.0#system-net-http-httpresponsemessage-requestmessage

Comment: I get a response and I can easily read the response. It's 401. However, I need to log the _request_ in order to show whether I am calling correctly.

Comment: would the answer from this question solve what you are trying to get?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924996/logging-request-response-messages-when-using-httpclient

Comment: If you need only log, you can follow this https://dev.to/nikolicbojan/log-httpclient-request-and-response-based-on-custom-conditions-in-net-core-412f

Comment: @AndreasAndersson that does not work because I want to log the headers as well. And I want to log the actual headers sent and not an approximate recreation of the headers because there are things internally in HttpClient that may alter them. Or not. I’m not sure.

Comment: @Den that is good but can I be sure that it logs what is actually sent? It’s just looking at properties on the request and logging them. Is there a guarantee that it will not be altered somewhere down the line?

Comment: Probably you should use Bearer instead of Basic in authorization value: `request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiToken);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cannot use any proxy solution (like Fiddler) then I can see 2 options. One is described in comments in your question to use `DelegatingHandler`. You can read more about this in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0). What is interesting is that `HttpClient` supports logging out of the box which is described in this section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#logging of the article which describes `DelegatingHandlers`

If you are worried that something will manipulate the outgoing request then you can implement option 2. This is to create temporary asp.net core application with `.UseHttpLogging()` middleware plugged in into pipeline as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0 That way you will know exactly how your request looks like from application which is being requested point of view. Now if you will point your azure function to you temporary app - you should see what gets send

Hope it helps

Comment: Option 2 is a great idea. Thank you for that.

Comment: @NielsBrinch no problem. Sad that it does not deserve a bounty though :P

Comment: No no it did deserve the bounty. What happened? I can't see where to put it.

Comment: Expired 39 minutes ago ... does that mean it's lost!?

Comment: Yup :) I was not starting bounty ever. But I think only accepted answers - or manually assigning bounty before grace period ends is giving the bounty. No worries ;) I will not be crying. Did you manage to find and solve your problem btw?

Comment: I will create a public service using your method so anyone can always get a mirror of their http request for troubleshooting purposes